# Are multi-dimensional arrays filled with null values when defined implicitly?

Tags: c#, arrays, class, multidimensional-array, null

I have:

`public static BlockQuadrant[] EditModeBlocks = new BlockQuadrant[9];`

but when I try to use them I get a null value exception, and apparently all of the values are equal to null. I thought this was a value **inside** my `BlockQuadrant` class, but I defined everything in the constructor. If this is the case, is there a way I can make it fill up the array with actual instances of `BlockQuadrant` instead of null values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you construct an array of *reference* objects, it constructs only an array, not the objects inside it. You need to initialize the individual objects by calling constructors.

You can take a shortcut using LINQ, like this:

```
public static BlockQuadrant[] EditModeBlocks = Enumerable
    .Range(0, 9)
    .Select(i => new BlockQuadrant())
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: @leaf68 `Enumerable.Range(start, count)` produces a sequence of nine numbers, zero through eight. `Select(...)` ignores these numbers, and replaces them with `new BlockQuadrant()`. Finally, `ToArray()` converts the resultant to an array.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a problem with looping through your array and `new`ing the elements?

```
for (int ii = 0; ii < EditModeBlocks.Length; ii++)
{
    EditModeBlocks[ii] = new BlockQuadrant();
}
```

With your initial statement, you've created an array with default values. For reference types, the default value is `null`.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to instantiate the each element in array before you use as the array contains null in its element.

```
public static BlockQuadrant[] EditModeBlocks = new BlockQuadrant[9];
```

In some static method use loop to instantiate them.

```
private static someMethod()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < EditModeBlocks.Length; i++)
    {
        EditModeBlocks[i] = new BlockQuadrant();
    }
}
```